# Make Form Maximized, but not Full Screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to make my Form1 Maximized, but not Full Screen, as differentiated by Maximized taking the entirety of the screen while leaving space dedicated to the Taskbar at the bottom. To clarify, I'd like my application to work how other applications traditionally work, such as Chrome or the MS Office suite when maximized. Definitely nothing fancy.

To make my application resize itself dynamically, I've calculated where buttons will fit relative to the height and width of the application. However, I discovered quickly that my application, in Maximized state, actually continued underneath the task bar (or, in reverse, the taskbar is entirely cut off by the application - it is Full Screen). My bottom-most buttons are actually cut off by the taskbar. After experimenting with different Form settings, I discovered this appears to be entirely the result of WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized setting.

I've tried various routes to counteract this behavior. First, I attempted to resize the maximum bounds programmatically, while leaving the Form's MaximumSize set to "0,0" (the default "resize me as needed" setting). I have this code in the Form_Load event:

```
    Me.MaximizedBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

and

```
    Me.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle).WorkingArea
```

However, these did not have any affect, even though the working area height is confirmed smaller than the form height. In fact, upon further testing, I have not been able to programmatically change the maximizedbounds at all, apart from manually in the form properties, setting the MaximumSize to 100,100. Does anyone have suggestions here?

I also tried to change the WindowsState = FormWindowState.Manual and readjust the form height this way:

```
    Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
    Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
```

Which makes the form closer to the dedicated dimensions, but makes the window movable and no longer covers the entirety of a traditionally maximized screen (it leaves about 20 pixels padding on all sides).

In the end, I'm at a bit of a loss on how to do this and would really appreciate some clarification. I have attempted other code I'd be glad to share, as well as similar questions on the forum, but none have helped me get my targeted behavior. I have a locked Taskbar on the most recent update to Windows 10, if those details make any difference.

Comment: A maximised form will work exactly as you want by default. If it's not, that suggests that your form doesn't have a border, i.e. you have set `FormBorderStyle` to `None`. Is that correct? If so, the way to get your desired behaviour is to change that. Is that possible.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, unfortunately, I can confirm that I already have the FormBoderStyle set to FixedSingle. I also have a menustrip enabled and MaximizeButton set to disabled.

Comment: I wonder whether this is actually working as it should and it's actually your calculations that are wrong. There's no good reason for you to be calculating the positions of controls as configuration should handle it automatically.  I suggest that you [read this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636-Anchor-amp-Dock-For-Automatic-Resizing) and see whether using `Dock` and/or `Anchor` properties as intended produces the expected results.

Comment: To confirm, I just created a new WinForms project, set the `FormBorderStyle` of the form to `FixedSingle`, added a `Button`, shifted the `Button` to the bottom-right corner and set its `Anchor` property to `Bottom, Right`. When I ran the project and maximised the form, the `Button` was positioned in the bottom-right corner, exactly as it should be. If you try that, does it work for you too?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thank you for your help so far - I think I'm close to better understand it. After confirming your method worked correctly on a new form, I compared the form settings with that of my project. It appears this issue is due to "MaximizeButton" = false. Toggling this button changes the functionality between "Maximized" and "Full Screen", which I confirmed on the new Form too.

Comment: Do you need to remove the user's ability to maximise and restore? If not then the solution is obvious. If you do then your issue certainly warrants further investigation, which I can do when I have time.

Comment: What appears to work is enabling the maximize button manually, but programmatically disabling it upon load. My intention moving forward is to definitely do some more research on anchors and panels to make my application more dynamic. I just COULDNT figure out why it was sized so unexpectedly. You have my thanks sir!

Comment: This is a typical vb.net hazard, the project item template does not encourage programmers to use a constructor.  So too much code ends up in the Load event handler.  Which fires too late to make the MaximizedBounds property work, the window is already created by then and already maximized with the default bounds.  Type "Public Sub New" and press enter.